# remove escape characters from a char

Tags: c++, c

I've been working with this for about 2 days now. I'm stuck, with a rather simple annoyance, but I'm not capable of solving it.

My programs basicly recieves a TCP connection from a PHP script. And the message which is send is stored in `char buffer[1024];`.
Okay this buffer variable contains an unique key, which is being compared to a `char key[1024] = "supersecretkey123";`

The problem itself is that these two does not equal - no matter what I do. 
I've been printing the buffer and key variable out just above eachother and by the look they are 100% identical. However my equalisation test still fails.

```
if(key == buffer) { // do some thing here etc }
```

So then I started searching the internet for some information on what could be wrong. I later realized that it might be some escape characters annoying me. But I'm not capable of printing them, removing them or even making sure they are there. So that's why I'm stuck - out of ideas on how to make these equal when the buffer variable matches the key variable.
Well the key does not chance, unless the declaration of the key is modified manually. The program itself is recieving the information and sending back information "correctly".

Thanks.

Comment: Are you comparing the values of the pointer or the contents of the memory the pointer points to?

Comment: When you do `key == buffer` your are actually comparing the memory addresses of the first `char` of each array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using C++ use `std::string` instead of `char []`. You cannot compare two `char []` in way you try to do this (they are pointers to memory), but it's possible with `std::string`.

If it's somehow mandatory to use `char[]` in your case, use `strcmp`.

Comment: Use of std::string is generally encouraged but there is no requirement to convert to std::string just to perform a compare. std::string only goes to char_traits to do it anyway, by the way, which itself uses memcmp in most implementations.

Comment: I didn't say he should use `std::string` just to make a comparsion. I think `std::string` is easier to use for not experienced programmers (and judging from a question Ubha is one).

Answer (score 5):

If you're using null terminated strings use proper api - `strcmp` and its variants.

Additionally size in declaration `char key[1024] = "supersecretkey123";` is not needed - either compiler will reduced it or stack/heap memory will be wasted.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `if(!strncmp(key,buffer,1024))`. See [this reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strncmp/) on `strncmp`.